# Covariance and mutable attribute

Tags: scala, attributes, covariance

Why I can't assign to the mutable attribute?

```
class X[+T](t: T) {
  var _t: T = t   // Error. Ok if this is val.
}
```

The error is:

```
covariant type T occurs in a contravariant position in type T of value _t_=
  var _t: T = t
```

---

I try to think about this.

- Suppose `B <: A`, which means `class B` is a subclass of `class A`.
- Then, `X[B] <: X[A]`.
- I can assign an `object xb` of `class X[B]` to an `instance xa` of `class X[A]`.
- Then we assign `xb._t (type B)` to `var _t: A` in `xa`.
- This seems to be fine.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I guess this is the problem. After `val xa: X[A] = xb`, `val xa` is like a pointer to the `xb object`. And `xa._t` actually have the memory layout of a type B object. However, since `xa._t` is mutable, I can assign another value of type A to `xa._t`. Now I have something of type B holding the data of type A, which is a problem.

Comment: Mutable things have to invariant since they are both consumers and producers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Not only you can assign something of type `A`, but you could also assign something of type `A` which would not be of type `B`. So you would end up violating the type soundness at runtime.

Here's a more easy-to-follow example. Suppose you have the nonvariant `Cell` type:

```
  class Cell[T](elem: T) {
    var curr: T = elem
  }
```

Now assume for a moment that this type was declared covariant instead, as in `Cell[+T]` - and that the code would pass the compiler type check (it doesn't). Then you could write the following problematic code:

```
val c1 = new Cell[String]("abc")
val c2: Cell[Any] = c1
c2.curr = 1
val s: String = c1.curr        // violates the type soundness at runtime
```

If `Cell` would be covariant, taken individually, each line of code would compile just fine. But taken together as a whole, these lines end up assigning an `Int` to a `String`. This would clearly throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

So even though the faulty line is the last one, actually it is the second line the one to blame, because the other ones are just too simple and too fundamental.
In natural language, this would translate as follows:

> A `Cell` of `String` is not also a `Cell` of `Any` because there are things
> you can do with a `Cell` of `Any` that you cannot do with a `Cell` of
> `String`. For example, you cannot assign an `Int` to the `curr` field of a
> `Cell` of `String`.

This is why, if you would make `Cell` covariant, the code would fail with the same error:

```
error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value curr_=
    var curr: T = elem
```